# Run WinCE exe in Linux OS using mono command

Tags: linux, mono, windows-ce

I have a WinCE code for matrix keypad downloaded from toradex site at [How to use Matrix Keypad](https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/how-to-use-matrix-keypad). I have tested in WinCE OS and working fine.

My actual program needs to be executed in Linux OS. I am using mono command. I tried the following:

```
mono program.exe
```

I got an exception

```
System.DllNotFoundException: `TdxAllLibraries.dll`.
```

Then I tried:

```
mono program.exe TdxAllLibrariesDll.dll
```

But still the same error.

I expect the wince exe should run in Linux OS using mono command. What can I do to run the wince exe on linux?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: @ZangMingJie ok sir

Answer (score 1):

That sample references Windows-CE specific libraries that are not available on Linux.
On the other side, if you plan to use our Linux-based Torizon, you can find instuctions about how to run .NET core here:
https://github.com/toradex/dot-net-core
and also a sample using
https://github.com/dotnet/iot
to access GPIO, same package supports also i2c.